# HTML5 SQLite database location

Tags: javascript, sqlite, html

I have an HTML5 database that I am creating in javascript, but there is no indication where this database is being stored.  I want to be able to query this table during development with more than just the safari tools.

I am using safari for Mac during the development.

Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `~/Library/Safari/Databases`. There should be a bunch of directories, each of which contains a SQLite3 database.